# Is it possible to create consecutive OR statements using Z3 expr_vectors?

Tags: c++, z3, smt, z3py, sat

I'm trying to create a constraint such that a value X is one of the members of the expr_vector such as,

```
context c;
expr_vector v(c);
expr x = c.int_const("x");
expr i1 = c.int_val(5);
expr i2 = c.int_val(7);
solver s(c);
s.add(x == i1 || x == i2); // this is what I want to create iteratively
```

I tried to create an expression by looping on expr_vector v to create the boolean expression but I failed.

What I basically want is to be able to write such an expression.

```
v.push_back(i1);
v.push_back(i2);
s.add(belongs(x, v));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is provided by the z3 API, and is called `expr_mk_or`, available [here](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/z3_09_09_8h_source.html#l02049)

You can also implement this as a loop: Start with a boolean-expression initialized to `false`, and in each iteration use the `or` combinator to string them together. If you post what you tried, we can point out what you might've done wrong.